# Eclipse - Android app, how to get multiple buttons to lead to multiple activities?

Tags: android, eclipse

I only tried using 2 buttons to test, but.. didn't end up working and it just crashes the app when they're pressed, please tell me how it should be coded, and a small explanation on why? it'll help me later on if I know why it does what it does.. here is my code

```
    import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.ads.AdView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class Loading extends Activity {

    Button button1;
    Button xcheats;
    Button pcheats;
    protected Context context;

    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_loading);
            button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
            xcheats = (Button)findViewById(R.id.xcheats);
            pcheats = (Button)findViewById(R.id.pcheats);

            button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    Intent intent3 = new Intent(context, Manual.class);
                                startActivity(intent3);   

                }


        });         
            xcheats.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, cheatsx.class);
                           startActivity(intent2);   

            }


    });

    }   
            public AdView adView;
          public void onCreate2(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_loading);

            String a1524e277372095 = null;
            // Create the adView
            adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, a1524e277372095);

          }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Intent intent3 = new Intent(Loading.this, Manual.class);
startActivity(intent3);
```

Your problem is probably your context.

Edit:
Here's the small explanation you've asked for: As you may already know, you need a context, but you forgot to initialize yours. That's why you were getting an error. What I did was just put a context. You could also have changed from:

```
protected Context context;
```

To:

```
protected Context context = this;
```

That it would probably work too.

Comment: The least you could do if you expect rep is to explain why.

Comment: My bad. I made an edit with a small explanation for anyone else who may have trouble with this.